# CTRL+Z in Object Mode takes me to last change in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

If Im in Object Mode and I want to undo changes in Object Mode by pressing CTRL+Z, Blender goes to Edit Mode (last object edited) and undos the changes there, deleting all changes done in Object Mode too.
I have looked around and havent find an answer, its a behavior that didnt use to happen before... dont know what changed. Already reinstalled.
Im using Blender 3.1. It happened in 3.0 too.

Comment: "*Its a behavior that didnt use to happen before...*" It has been like this for quite a while, since 2.8 series as far as I know

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos okay, but do you know how undoing in object mode without going to edit mode works? what shortcut should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The *Global Undo* option needs to be enabled:

1. Open your preferences (*Edit > Preferences*)
2. Switch to the *System* tab
3. Scroll to the *Memory & Limits* panel
4. Enable *Global Undo*