Undo (CRTL+Z) will always Switch me to edit mode!
I'm using Blender 4.0 and Blender 4.1.
If I'm moving something in object mode, or posing for an animation in pose mode; If I press undo (Ctrl + Z) The program will switch to Edit Mode and not revert the change I want in the other modes. It will still undo in Edit Mode.
It has gotten to the point where I gotta do everything perfect or remember the last position in the other modes.
I normally solve my Blender problem on my own but with this, I'm stumped.
Idk if I pressed some weird button to cause this, but any help that could possible stop this would be appreciated.

See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277894/186135

@kid-with-glasses Thank you, this definitely solved it. Strange that it was unchecked. It felt like it was on in all previous versions of blender I used.

Under Preferences > System check Global Undo.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
